# Android Studio не подписывает файл…

Tags: android-studio, цифровая-подпись

… или подписывает, но я не понимаю ничего!

В общем, есть такая проблема: решил выкладывать APK в Firebase App Distribution, ранее выкладывал в GitHub Releases, мой приятель устанавливал это приложение себе на телефон (Nokia, Android 9), но когда я предложил ему устанавливать приложение из Firebase, он сказал, что его телефон отказывается устанавливать, по его мнению из-за того, что приложение не подписано.

Я решил сделать специальные подписанные файлы, кликал в Android Studio `Build > Generate Signed APK…`, вроде как подписал, но не подписал — та же проблема, говорит мой приятель. Я решил погуглить это дело, но нашёл лишь то, что и так делал — в лёгкую все подписывают приложение прямо из студии. Проверить мне так и не удалось, обычный способ — распаковать и найти `META-INF/CERT.RSA` работает только для V1 Sign, а я не хочу оставаться в стороне и подписывать V2 Sign!

Помогите, пожалуйста, объясните, как проверить реально ли проблема в подписи, а то я уже так запутался, ничего не ясно!

Приложение написано на Kotlin, Android Studio 3.5.2, минимальный SDK 28, собираю при помощи Gradle.

Comment: При подписании указываю V1 и V2, работает даже на Android 6.0.

Comment: Возможно у вас дело в том, что APK подписываются по разному и ваш друг видит сообщение о том, что подписи не совпадают и установка приведёт к потере данных. В этом случае надо проверить как подписывали раньше и чем тот способ отличается от нынешнего. ВОзможно раньше вы подписывали дебажным ключом. Или теперь дебажным. Или дебажные ключи с разных компьютеров. Или вы используете подписывание на стороне гугла. В общем - мало информации.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, ранее я просто нажимал `Build > Build APK`, и, вроде как в настройках проекта прописан `$signingConfigs.debug`

Comment: @МаксимsaysReinstateMonica вроде как и способ v1+v2 не работает для него

Comment: @dimon4ezzz, получается, ранее у вас друг дебажной версией таки пользовался. Значит пускай удаляет её и ставит новую, правильно подписанную.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, для проверки и установки подписи существует `apksigner` — утилита командной строки, которую, кстати, советуют на [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com). С помощью неё мне удалось увидеть, какие подписи есть: `apksigner verify -v --print-certs *.apk`. Я не знаю почему, но подписи, почему-то разные получились в итоге. Буду собирать только одним способом теперь.